# How do you resize DVD subs in VLC?

Tags: windows, dvd, vlc-media-player, subtitles

Situation:

Recently I bought a DVD with subtitles. When I play the DVD using Windows Media Player and PowerDVD, the subtitles are just right but when I use VLC, the font becomes very large. So large that the sentence is not completed in the video screen.

What I know:

I am tweaking my VLC and read a few posts. It says that DVD subs are recorded as images so changing the font size would not do. I managed to shift the subs up and down.

What I have:

VLC v. 1.0.5
Windows OS

Comment: you can't do it. DVD subtitles are actually a separate video stream instead of a text stream, therefore resizing it make it worse

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Tools` -> `Preferences` -> `Subtitles and OSD` (**or** <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).  There, you will find an option to change the subtitle size, among other configurations.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know DVD subtitles are image-based and never affected by this setting.

Comment: *The font settings can be adjusted for plain text subtitle formats. Font settings cannot be changed for rich text (e.g. ASS) or **bitmap (e.g. DVD) subtitle formats.*** [VLC HowTo/Adjust subtitle font settings](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Adjust_subtitle_font_settings/)